# getLocation() always returns null, searching Twitter

Tags: java, get, twitter, twitter4j

every time i search through tweets for location it is returned null, here is my code, any ideas?

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("8888888888888888888");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("8888888888888888888888888");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("8888888888888888888888");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("8888888888888888888888888888");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
Query query = new Query("London");
query.setRpp(1000000);


QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();


for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
  Tweet t = (Tweet) tweets.get(i);
  String user = t.getFromUser();
  GeoLocation l = t.getGeoLocation();
  String locNam = t.getLocation();
  String msg = t.getText();
  Date d = t.getCreatedAt();
  println(locNam + "");
```

i can get the `getGeoLocation()` working fine, they are few and far between but i do get some however with the `getLocation` every search is returned null.

any help would be appreciated! cheers

Comment: You should change your OAuth keys.

Comment: Interesting question. Let me try it on my twitter app, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Okay... I'm screwing around, and I'm getting a big pile of null as well. You're using Twitter4j, I'm using jtwitter http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php  and we're getting the same results... I never really bothered with location, but this got me curious.

Comment: @SaviourSelf it doesnt make sense does it?! any clue as to why?

Answer (score 4):

@JohnSmith, I got it working.

Turns out Status.getLocation() (or Tweet.getLocation()) works if the user clicks the button to ADD location to their tweets. If you choose NOT to do this, then your location will not be posted, and will return null.

I tested this using my test Twitter account: [@Saviour_Self](https://twitter.com/Saviour_Self)  In my most recent post, I gave a location, and when I ran my application, it returned the location. I ran a loop to get all of the status updates from my account, only one of which returned a location.

```
for (Status s : tweets) {
    System.out.println(s.getLocation()); //Returned the location of the tweet.
    System.out.println(s.getUser().getLocation());  /* Returned the 
                                              User Profile  Location (always constant)*/
}
```

Keep in mind, I used JTwitter to do this, and not Twitter4j, but the results should be the same. Go ahead and test your program on my account. Only the most recent post will return a non-null location.

Comment: great help there and thank you, but im still having issues.
Mainly with finding twitter4j's alternative to `getUser` i tried `t.getUser().getLocation()` but it doesnt recognise the `getUser()` function thank you for your help however, and ill try to delve a little deeper into how i can access this :)